# UITextView not setting text

Tags: swift, uitextview

I've been breaking my head over this, but for some reason, I can't see any text that I set in the ".text" property. Below is my code:

```
        var container = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 200))
        var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 90, width: 300, height: 200), textContainer: container)
        destinationViewController.view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        textView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textView.text = "Testing"
        textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Natural
        textView.font = UIFont(name:"Times New Roman", size: UIFont.systemFontSize())
        textView.delegate = self
```

The backgroundColor is visible after the destination viewController loads, but the text isn't visible. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Because you had set `textColor` to white.

Comment: But my background color is blue; shouldn't that still show through?

Comment: Try setting the font size.

Comment: I thought I had set that with: textView.font = UIFont(name:"Times New Roman", size: UIFont.systemFontSize())

Comment: I think it is to with NSTextContainer. If you add textview to frame, the text gets displayed but not with NSTextContainer.

Comment: Oh wow!  You were right! It was NSTextContainer the entire time! Thank you for helping me!